# Retrieve customer attribute properties

Tags: admin, frontend, validation, prototype-js

I am going to add front-end validation for customer attribute by adding CSS classes `'validate-length'` and `'maximum-length-xx'` in the input tag.

I need to find how I can retrieve, for example, the Maximum Text Length value of customer attribute 'First Name'.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me for the `telephone` attribute. I addapted the script for `firstname`, but please check it again, in case I missed something.

```
$firstname = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'firstname');
$rules = $firstname->getValidateRules();
$validationClasses = array();
if (isset($rules['min_text_length'])){
    $validationClasses['validate-length'] = 1;
    $validationClasses['minimum-length-'.$rules['min_text_length']] = 1;
}
if (isset($rules['max_text_length'])){
    $validationClasses['validate-length'] = 1;
    $validationClasses['maximum-length-'.$rules['max_text_length']] = 1;
}

$class = implode(' ', array_keys($validationClasses));
//use $class in the form.
```